# How to get current item index Knp paginator

Tags: php, symfony, twig, knppaginator

I am trying to get the current index of the item that is current displaying in knp paginator bundle, atm i have something like this:

```
{% for index, post in posts %}

    {{ index + 1 }}

{% endfor %}
```

However this only displays for example 1 - 10, even when i am on page 2. It is supposed to show items 11-20 on page, 21-30 on page 3,... but it gets reset every time.

I solved it by using:

```
{{ pagination.getItemNumberPerPage * (pagination.getCurrentPageNumber - 1) + index + 1 }}
```

but this is a very messy solution which i don't want to use.

Are there any alternatives for this?

Answer (score 9):

I was just looking for a cleaner solution to this also, and found that the getPaginationData method works pretty well. To display the range, you could do something like:

```
{{ pagination.getPaginationData.firstItemNumber }} - {{ pagination.getPaginationData.lastItemNumber }}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your answer was just what i was searching for!

Answer (score 3):

Use this code:

```
{{ pagination.getPaginationData.firstItemNumber + loop.index - 1 }}
```

Answer (score -1):

{{ pagination.getPaginationData.firstItemNumber + loop.index0 }}